# IO error during HTTP execution

Tags: webharvest

I used the web-harvest for 5 month and I tried to get the content of webs with this syntax:

```
<var-def name="raw">
<html-to-xml outputtype="pretty" usecdata="false">
    <http url="${URL.toString()}" />           
    </html-to-xml>      
</var-def>
```

I'd gotten the content, but recently I get this error:

```
ERROR - IO error during HTTP execution for URL: http://google.com
org.webharvest.exception.HttpException: IO error during HTTP execution for URL:    http://google.com
at org.webharvest.runtime.web.HttpClientManager.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.HttpProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.getBodyTextContent(Unknown  Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.getBodyTextContent(Unknown  Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.getBodyTextContent(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.HtmlToXmlProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.VarDefProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.gui.ScraperExecutionThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at  org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocke tFactory.java:140)
at  org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
at  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
at  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
... 15 more
```

I tied it on another pc and it worked correctly, but on my pc I got this error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Might be a firewall, or internet connection issue. Try accessing the site first, or running the application as an administrator.

Comment: No, it worked correctly and internet connection is connected, In fact I got "heap space out of RAM" error and I searched about it and concluded that I should remove webharvest.config file from temp folder. after that I faced with this error. I tested it on another PC with the same internet connection and it worked there.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, update your java version to java 8 and it should fix the issue.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html